# MongoDB PyMongo basic help - extracting info from a document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I think this is a fairly basic question, but I can't figure this part out. So, basically, in my code, I have isolated a document, like so:

```
document = collection.find_one(name)
```

And now that I have this document, I want to know how to print out a certain key for this specific document. So, basically, this document looks like this right now:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectID("...")
"name": ABCD
"info": {
      "description" : "XYZ"
      "type" : "QPR"
}}
```

And I want to know how I can extract and print "XYZ" using the variable "document" that has the entire document in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document` is a [regular Python dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
print(document["info"]["description"])
```

This, as well as, a lot of relevant PyMongo basic usage information is covered in the [PyMongo Tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#documents) - make sure to study it.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a dictionary

```
print(document['info']['description'])
```

or if you are not sure if your document contains the right keys

```
info = document.get('info', None)
if info:
    print(document.get('description', 'No description'))
```